# How to fix Laravel Class not found error exception

Tags: php, laravel, git

Help me sort this error out I have removed the class but when I run `php artisan` I get this error:

> Class 'Swap\Laravel\SwapServiceProvider' not found.
> I have removed it from the **app.php** file in **config** and the **composer.json** file.

in my log

> local.ERROR: Class 'Swap\Laravel\SwapServiceProvider' not found
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0):
> Class 'Swap\Laravel\SwapServiceProvider' not found at
> C:\laragon\www\myapp-web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php:208)

I tried to create a new branch and still getting the same error.

Comment: did you cache your configuration?

Comment: how  `php artisan cache` command?

Comment: did you run `php artisan config:cache` at some point? if so you need to delete the cached config

Comment: yes but I can't run any command

Answer (score 2):

You cached your configuration which means you will have to delete that cache config file since that is what is being used and has the reference to the class that does not exist anymore.

Delete the file `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

If this is running on your localhost there is no need to cache your configuration. If this is deployed to a server, then that would be a good time to cache the configuration and routes.

Comment: Still getting the same error after deleting config.php

Comment: then there is still something referencing that class, the fact that the error is coming from the `ProviderRepository` would lean towards it is still referenced in a config file

Comment: its deployed and running smothly in localhost but on the server its broken

Comment: okay and on what host did you remove this from the `app.php` config file and on which host did you delete the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file?

Comment: on the server. the localhost is ok

Comment: @Wells remove `bootstrap/cache/packages.php` as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222808/discussion-between-wells-and-lagbox).